# pixiJS ignore mouse event

Tags: mouseevent, pixi.js

I have a UI layer and a Game layer.
that the UI layer falls transparently on the Game layer.
And when I click on the sprites inside the Game layer.
I do not receive events.
I want the events to reach the bottom layer as well.
I tried the codes but it didn't work.

```
        ui.on('pointerdown',e=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

With new feature in pixi.js v7+, you can use EventBoundary to reach your goal.
Just receive these events sent from the UI layer, and forward them to the Game layer, with the code like this:
const boundary = new PIXI.EventBoundary(GameLayerRoot);
[
'pointerdown',
'pointerup',
'pointermove',
'pointerover',
'pointerout',
'wheel',
].forEach((event) => {
UIArea.addListener(event, (e) => boundary.mapEvent(e));
});

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's a limitation of Pixijs to avoid firing multiple events when there is overlap of containers with **interactive** property set to **true**. It will only fire the event on the container that is in foreground (the last one added to the stage).

You can probably work around it by either creating **PIXI.Graphics** for your UI elements with **alpha** set to 0 and **interactive** set to **true**, or create an entire Interactive elements layer and checking for overlap between elements.

**Edit:**
I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, and you potentially could have to rethink your project.

The other way you could accomplish this is by ignoring the interactive attribute, adding a click event on the entire document, and checking with your containers which one has implemented a IClickable interface you made up, then checking if the pointer position overlaps with the interactive area you calculate manually for each container. you can then fire an event for all sprites under your pointer, even if they are on top of each other.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Think you can tell me the details of what you are trying to accomplish? 
Is your entire UI layer interactive? Does it cover the entire stage? Do you need it to?

Comment: Yes I need it and it covers the whole scene